# Restaurar um banco de dados SQL SERVER a partir do um arquivo mdf

Tags: sql-server

Estou precisando restaurar um banco de dados a partir de um arquivo MDF.
Peguei o mdf de outra máquina para ser restaurado numa máquina principal.

Ao realizar o attach, vinculando o arquivo MDF, ocorre um erro dizendo que o arquivo não pode ser localizado, porém o endereço do arquivo exibido é o do endereço da máquina que recuperei o arquivo MDF e não o da máquina principal.

Tentei realizar o attach via comando especificando os endereços via comando:

> sp_attach_single_file_db

Conforme explo abaixo:

```
exec sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'base_recuperada',
@physname = 'C:\sqldata\dados.mdf'
```

Ao executar o comando me ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
Mensagem 5120, Nível 16, Estado 5, Linha 15
Não é possível abrir o arquivo físico "I:\DADOS_SERVER\base.mdf". Erro do sistema operacional 2: "2(O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.)".
Falha de ativação do arquivo. O nome do arquivo físico "I:\DADOS_SERVER\base.ldf" pode estar incorreto.
Mensagem 1813, Nível 16, Estado 2, Linha 15
Não foi possível abrir o novo banco de dados 'base_recuperada'. CREATE DATABASE foi anulado.
```

Se olharem o endereço da localização na mensagem acima verão que o endereço que está referenciando continua errado e não consigo setar o local correto.

Mesmo depois dessa situação tentei uma terceira alternativa, criei um banco novo e tentei vincular o arquivo mdf ao qual estou restaurando e ocorreu o mesmo problema de local errado.

Não consigo recuperar um bkp de banco e nem desatachar o arquivo do banco da outra máquina. Somente com o mdf que possuo restaurar na máquina principal.

O que sugerem de procedimento ou o que seria o correto?

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro acontece porque está faltando o arquivo ldf.
Uma alternativa é criar um novo banco e atachar o mdf nele. Pode ser feito via comando:

```
CREATE DATABASE dados ON (FILENAME = N'C:\sqldata\dados.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

O `ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` vai recriar o log que está faltando

Comment: Executei o teu código porém continuou dando o mesmo problema. Mapeando os endereços da outra máquina ao invés da máquina que estou restaurando. Segue:

Mensagem 5120, Nível 16, Estado 5, Linha 33
Não é possível abrir o arquivo físico "I:\DADOS_SERVER\base.mdf". Erro do sistema operacional 2: "2(O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.)".
Falha de ativação do arquivo. O nome do arquivo físico "I:\DADOS_SERVER\base.ldf" pode estar incorreto.
Mensagem 1813, Nível 16, Estado 2, Linha 33
Não foi possível abrir o novo banco de dados 'base_recuperada'. CREATE DATABASE foi anulado.